# TypeError: can't call method "getSheetName of undefined - Google Apps Script code

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

This code fails with:

```
TypeError: can't call method "getSheetName" of undefined. (line 7)
```

Code:

```
function onOpen() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    var sheetnames = [];

    for(var i=0; i < sheets.length+1; i++)
        sheetnames.push(sheets[i].getSheetName());

    return ss.toast(sheetnames, "Greetings!", 300);
}
```

when this works:

```
function onOpen() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    var sheetnames = [];

    for(var i=0; i < sheets.length+1; i++)
        sheetnames.push(sheets[0].getSheetName());

    //Returns: Nimikirjasto,Nimikirjasto,Nimikirjasto,Nimikirjasto,Nimikirjasto
    // Text is too long to fit to the popup.
    return ss.toast(sheetnames, "Greetings!", 300);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code.

### Code

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shs = ss.getSheets(), num = shs.length;
  var sheetnames = [];

  for(var i=0; i<num; i++) {
    sheetnames.push(shs[i].getSheetName());
  }

  return ss.toast(sheetnames, "Greetings!", 300);
}
```

### Explained

The sheets are zero based (as arrays are). So, adding an extra sheet in the iteration will result in an error (because of an unknown sheet index).

### Remark

Your second code will always work, because the first entry (zero) will always be found.
Try this, if you want to stack the sheet names:

```
sheetnames.push(shs[i].getSheetName() + '\n');
```

### Reference

- https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml
- http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Comment: But the first code has `i` init as `0`, which is same in the second, but it still fails. Unless, I'm overlooking and/or missing something.

Comment: @rautamiekka See `sheets.length + 1`

Comment: Will take time before I fully get into the understanding of this. Outta interest, why did you add the brackets to the `for` I didn't have there ?

Comment: @rautamiekka Added some useful references, for those new to JavaScript.

Comment: Anyway, it's fixed, so thanks for that :)